# Simple Entity PHP extension but Doctrine creates 2 tables - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created two entities. A main one and an extension of one.

```
class Main {

    $protected $id;

}

class MainExtension extends Main {

    $protected $field_name;

}
```

My Yaml:

```
Main:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
            strategy: AUTO
```

-

```
MainExtension:
    type: entity
    fields:
        field_name:
            type: integer
```

The problem is when I update the DB schema it creates two tables, one for Main and one for MainExtension, where I want just the MainExtension one. The MainExtension one works perfectly, and will pick up fields/properties set in the Main one, but I just need it to stop creating the 'Main' one too (without just deleting the table or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'Main' entity, simply change this:

```
type: entity
```

...to this:

```
type: mappedSuperclass
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created two separate entities, declared them as entities, and as expected you have got 2 tables in db.

If you want only MainExtension, you can delete the entity declaration of Main entity. Or use a [inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) in the doctrine. For example [Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance).